# Message Digest in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sha256, message-digest, cryptoswift

I need to generate Message Digest in Swift with SHA-256 variant with SALT. I am using CryptoSwift library in Swift for all the encryption/decryption. Now I am stuck at generating Message Digest which matches with Java code in Android as below. If someone can help me out of this. Thanks in advance.

Library I am using is Swift : [CryptoSwift](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift)

Java Code used for generating MD with Salt using SHA-256

```
public static String generateMessageDigest(String message,String salt) {
    try {
        MessageDigest msDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        msDigest.update(salt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] digest = msDigest.digest(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        return Base64.encodeBase64String(digest);
    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

**Note** : I need MD with **SALT**

Comment: Isn't this just `BASE64(SHA256(salt + message))`? Do you really need a library for that?

Comment: Yes it is just that, however how to do it with real code that was required.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I managed to find the solution on my own and below is the answer.

```swift
func getHashedPassword(passwordToHash:String, salt:String) -> String {
    let combinedString = "\(salt)\(passwordToHash)"
    let result =  Digest.sha256(combinedString.bytes)
    return Data(bytes: result).base64EncodedString()
}
```